# The minimal angle between a vector and a subspace, given another minimal angle

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Denote $\theta$ to be the minimal angle between any two vectors in $X$. 
Denote $\alpha$ to be an angle between (1) some vector  $y\in X$ and (2) some linear subspace spanned by $K<d$ other vectors in $X$.

What is $\alpha^*$, the minimal possible $\alpha$, given $d,K$ and $\theta$?

For example, if $K=1$ then $\alpha^*=\theta$. Also, if $K\geq2$ and $\pi>(K+2)\theta$ then $\alpha^*=0$, since then $y$ and the linear subspace can all fit together in a single 2D plane.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure you are right in the second example. Yes, you may fit $K+2$ vectors in a single plane, but it may happen to be impossible to squeeze the rest $N-(K+2)$ vectors...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood the question: $N$ is not a parameter. But then we definitely can set $N=K+1$ with no harm, can't we?

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is no problem to set $N=K+1$. In fact, I'll just drop the $N$ parameter (number of vectors in $X$), as it is not relevant (let me know if there are any objections). Thanks!